# JOINING TWO SQL statements

Tags: mysql, join

I appologise for the NOOB question, but I just can't get my head around JOINING results from two tables.

I have one table (tableA) that links entries with categories has the columns entry_id and cat_id

I have another table (tableB) that counts the number of times entry_id has been viewed against a timestamp

I want to get a list of entry_id's from tableB sorted by the number of times they have been viewed and filtered by cat_id from tableA.

I have the two SQL statements, but can't figure out how to put them together.

Statement 1 - Get entry_id's within a particular category:

```
SELECT entry_id FROM tableA WHERE cat_id = ""
```

Statement 2 - Get a sorted list of entry_id's from tableB:

```
SELECT entry_id FROM tableB GROUP BY entry_id ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you read any tutorials? W3Schools is a good place to start. http://www.w3schools.com/sql and more specifically http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Hi Kevin - Yeah, I've read a whole bunch of tutes I'm just being very slow(!) Thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT
  tableb.entry_id,
FROM
  tableb
  INNER JOIN tablea
    ON tableb.entry_id = tablea.entry_id
    AND tablea.cat_id = ""
GROUP BY
  tableb.entry_id
ORDER BY
  COUNT(*) DESC
```

Comment: Ah - a slightly different approach. I'll try them both out. Thanks Hsan!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  A.entry_id, Count(B.entry_id) Viewed
FROM TableA A
 LEFT JOIN TableB B
    ON A.entry_id = B.entry_id
WHERE A.Cat_Id = 5 -- your cat_id
GROUP BY A.entry_id
ORDER BY Count(B.entry_id) DESC
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks Hamlet - Thats the first time I've got a handle on the whole assign a letter to represent a table thing. Cheers :)

Comment: @Tomtids In above solution you have loss entries which never viewed.

Comment: The accepted answer actually retrieves the correct information for me. I only want the entry ids where they match the current category id... Thanks for your help.